# How to remove vue feather icons

Tags: vue.js, feathericons

I installed vue-feather icons with yarn add vue-feather-icons but after that I found a better icons elsewhere and I want to remove it from the project. What command should I use? Thank you.

Comment: just remove it. if you use it somewhere replace it with the new icons there.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall a dependency with `yarn`, use the [`remove` command](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/remove/):

```
yarn remove <packageName> --<flag>
```

Removing `vue-feather-icons` is then:

```
yarn remove vue-feather-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run `yarn remove vue-feather-icons` at the source folder of your project and the package will be removed from your node_modules and package.json.